# How to change the color of my buttons on Mac OS?

Tags: java, jframe

I'm having a problem changing the color of my button background, I'm just starting to learn how to do the GUI and I have the following code which works perfectly on Windows, but I use Mac OS.

Can you please help me with this?

I already added the buttons and then changed the color but when running it, it pop-ups the window with the 9 buttons but all of them are in color white and the background is red, as you see I set them up on color blue.

```
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        b2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        b3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        b4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        b5.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        b6.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        b7.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        b8.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        b9.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 500);
```

Comment: Try commenting out the `this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default way to paint buttons on OSX and Windows seems to be different.

Since your question is broad, I'm not quite sure what the expected behavior is, so here are some solutions to your problem:

I just tested on my Mac, and what you need to do is to specify that the buttons should be opaque:

```
b1.setOpaque(true);
```

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it might be required for you to specify that the border shouldn't be painted either:

```
b1.setBorderPainted(false);
```

If you don't specify that the border shouldn't be painted, you're going to get a square with a blue background and a button with the default color in the middle.

If you want something that looks the same on both operating systems, you should use the following line in your JFrame:

```
try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() );
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This last way will make you lose the OSX / Windows look and feel, though, but the buttons will probably look more like what you're expecting.